# Queue.qsize() doesn't have the same result compared with Queue.empty()

Tags: python, queue

In one situation, I use Queue.empty() to judge whether Queue is empty, however, it returns True for Queue.empty() and returns 1 for Queue.qsize(). And actually, I put one element in the queue, so Queue.get return element instead of None.

Code like below:

```
q = Queue.Queue()
q.put(elem)

print q.empty() # True
print q.qsize() # 1
elem = q.get()  # Not None
```

I notice in [doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html), qsize only returns approximate size of the queue, so I shouldn't rely on that result, however, I really put one elem in the queue and I could get it from that, why q.empty() returns True, it's strange to me.

Thanks and waits for your reply

===============================

Add simplified detail code as suggested:

```
def f1(q):
    q.put(elem)

def f2(q):
    while not q.empty():
        elem = q.get() # not arrive here because q is empty()

q = Queue.Queue()
f1(q)
f2(q)
```

Comment: Is this the exact code you're running and experiencing this behavior? Because when I run at it works as expected (`q.empty()` returns `False`).

I guess the reason that the documentation says `qsize` returns approximate size is that this method does not use a lock, so it's possible that the value returned mismatches the real size, if other threads are modifying the queue (by `put/get`).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I add some codes as your suggestion, it shouldn't be related with lock because no multi-thread/process used here~

Comment: I just copied the code above, and added a `print` before getting elem from queue to show the code reaches there. Ran it and it worked fine, printing out that `elem` is getting from `queue`, meaning the queue was not empty. Could you specify which platform you're experiencing this behavior? OS, arch, Python implementation, Python version?

Comment: it's Red Hat, with Python v2.7,  yes it's a little strange to me too, thanks for your kindly help